# using only javascript to prompt user to choose at least one checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have a HTML form which already prompts users to fill empty fields. And this is the script that I am using:

```
<!-- Script to prompt users to fill in the empty fields -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
                    e.target.setCustomValidity("");
                    if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                        e.target.setCustomValidity("To continue, you must correctly fill in the missing fields.");
                    }
                };
                elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
                    e.target.setCustomValidity("");
                };
            }
        });
    </script>
```

This script works flawlesly and it brings up a nice prompt that looks like this:

[image]

It works for all the input text fields, but I need another script  that will **(a)** check if at least one checkbox you can see at the bottom of the form is checked, and **(b)** will bring up a prompt which is styled the same way as the one above.

I looked at other posts and wrote the below script. I referenced checkboxes by their IDs and somehow used the function `function(e)` from the above script. Well it won't work for me but I must be close...

```
<!-- Script which prompts user to check at least one checkbox -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        if (
            document.getElementById("linux-c-arm-checkbox").checked == false &&
            document.getElementById("linux-eda-cad-checkbox").checked == false &&
            document.getElementById("linux-blender-checkbox").checked == false &&
            document.getElementById("linux-photo-checkbox").checked == false &&
            document.getElementById("linux-audio-checkbox").checked == false &&
            document.getElementById("linux-latex-checkbox").checked == false &&
            document.getElementById("linux-desktop-checkbox").checked == false &&
            document.getElementById("linux-office-checkbox").checked == false
        ){
            function(e) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("");
                if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                    e.target.setCustomValidity("Please choose at least one checkbox.");
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone help me solve this by using javascript without JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though there is no way you can put required attribute on a checkbox group and do the validation for atleast one selection, here is a workaround solution. Do the changes accordingly on your HTML.

It takes a hidden textbox as the placeholder of the selected checkbox group. If atleast one is selected the hidden field will also have the value.

```js
function setAccount() {
      if (document.querySelectorAll('input[name="gender"]:checked').length > 0)
          document.querySelector("#socialPlaceholder").value = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value;
      else
          document.querySelector("#socialPlaceholder").value = "";
}

function invalidMsg(textbox) {
      if (textbox.value == '') {
          textbox.setCustomValidity('Please select at least one account');
      } else {
          textbox.setCustomValidity('');
      }
}
```

```html
<form target="_blank">
    <b>Accounts</b>
    <input type="text" id="socialPlaceholder" required value="" style="width:0px;height:0px;position: relative;left:-30px;opacity: 0;" oninvalid="invalidMsg(this)"/><br/>

    <label>Facebook<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="facebook" onClick="setAccount()"/></label>
    <label>Twitter<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="twitter" onClick="setAccount()"/></label>
    <label>Google Plus<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="google_plus" onClick="setAccount()"/></label>
    <label>Instagram<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="instagram" onClick="setAccount()"/></label>
    </br>
    </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <br/><br/>
    NOTE: Submit without selecting any account to see the validation message
</form>
```

Comment: Hey. Your solution also shows the prompt if I check at least one checkbox.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. I have verified it multiple times. Which browser you are using ?

Comment: I am on Chromium. It is the same on Firefox.

Comment: Fixed a minor bug. Please check now.

Comment: I have one more problem when implementing this. It prompt prints `To continue, you must correctly fill in the missing fields.` instead of the `Please select at least one account`. It looks like the first script's output overwrites the second script's output..

Comment: Ok, if you have already have validation message through your script. You can simply remove the oninvalid attribute on the hidden input.

Comment: Hey I tried this and it won't help. I noticed one more abnormality. Now I have to press submit twice for the form to actually submit.

Answer (score 1):

Your `e` is null, because you use self executing function inside `if` and does not pass any event for it.

Try changing `e.target` to `document.getElementById("linux-office-checkbox")` or other not-checked element.

---

In jQuery I would check if any checkbox is selected by doing `$('.checkboxClass:checked').length > 0`

Comment: Hey, this didn't work. Should I also change `e` in `function(e)` somehow?